# How to create an animation for StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Like other website when you hover your mouse on an Item, the information pop out or move up (from a single text to multi text etc..) 
I wanna archive that in UWP as well

```
<Grid>
   <Image source="1.png"/>
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBlock Text="1"/>
       <TextBlock Text="2"/>
       <TextBlock Text="3"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

How can I create an animation that the stack default hide under the "Grid" and when there is a mouse hover the "StackPanel" move from Text 1 to 3 ?

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DoubleAnimation` to animate the `Opacity` of `TextBlock` from 0~1.

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardSample1">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Storyboard.TargetName="txb1" Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardSample2">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Storyboard.TargetName="txb2" Completed="DoubleAnimation_Completed_2"/>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Name="StoryboardSample3">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2" To="1"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Storyboard.TargetName="txb3" />
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/Assets/dog.jpg"/>
        <StackPanel PointerEntered="StackPanel_PointerEntered">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txb1" Text="1" FontSize="30" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txb2" Text="2" FontSize="30" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txb3" Text="3" FontSize="30" Opacity="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void StackPanel_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StoryboardSample1.Begin();
}

private void DoubleAnimation_Completed(object sender, object e)
{
    StoryboardSample2.Begin();
}

private void DoubleAnimation_Completed_2(object sender, object e)
{
    StoryboardSample3.Begin();
}
```

Please read the [Animations in XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/xaml-animation) for more details.

[image]